# Подключить созданную заранее базу данных

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Как можно подключить готовую бд `sqlite` в приложение. Бд содержит всего одну таблицу на 2 поля, id и наименование. Потом, допустим, вывести данные в `listview` или `Textview`. Может ссылки есть на уроки, а то что-то гуглил и не нашел. Нужен простейший пример.

Comment: Вот здесь есть вполне информативный ответ. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880061/how-to-connect-sqlite-database-to-netbeans

Comment: Это немного не то, мне надо в своё разрабатываемое приложение добавить бд и потом уже в нем с бд проводить  манипуляции то есть вывод данных в текствью или листвью и тп

Comment: Там есть ссылка на tutorialspoint, где говорится, как подключить sqlite и как с ним работать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делал нечто подобное, вот код `SQLiteOpenHelper`, проверяет наличие базы с указанным именем, если такой нет, копирует из assets базу в папку приложения.

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, int version) throws IOException {
        super(context, name, null, version);

        File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(name);

        if (!dbFile.exists()) {
            dbFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(name);
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dbFile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (is.read(buffer) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer);
            }

            os.flush();
            os.close();
            is.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}
```